# API REST User Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest

Hi I have a problem or do not know how to do it. I created a REST API . Here users_controller code for the API. I want to do so that when I create a new user or tested the same user ( login) is already in the database . When the same user in the database returns the error .
Please Help!:)

```
module Api
  module V1

    class UsersController < ApplicationController # Api::BaseController
      before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:create, :index]

      respond_to :json

      def index
        #respond_with

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html {render text: "Your data was sucessfully loaded. Thanks"}
          format.json { render text: User.last.to_json }
        end
      end

      def show
        respond_with User.find(params[:id])
      end

      def create
        respond_with User.create(login: params[:login],
         email: params[:email],
         password: params[:password],
         spam: params[:spam],
         male: params[:male],
         facebookid: params[:facebookid]
         )
      end

      def update
        respond_with User.update(params[:id], params[:users])
      end

      def destroy
        respond_with User.destroy(params[:id])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code.

```
def create
  @user=User.find_by_login(params[:login])
  if @user.present?
    render :status=>401, :json=> ["Login already present"]
  else
    respond_with User.create(login: params[:login],
         email: params[:email],
         password: params[:password],
         spam: params[:spam],
         male: params[:male],
         facebookid: params[:facebookid]
         )
      render :status=>401, :json=> ["Login already present"]
  end
end
```